# How to get access token from auth0 using spring boot oauth2? I want to use password grant type. I have client id and client secret with me

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, auth0, java-17

How to get access token from auth0 using spring boot3 and spring securtiy 6 with java 17 using Auth0 provider?

We want our applicaition to act oauth2 client. I want to use password grant type/Implicit. I have client id and client secret, and user id and password with me.

I didnt find much resources to try

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Auth0 CLI](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cli) to create access tokens. Using implicit flow is not recommended and password grant is even worse. It bypasses the whole pint of delegated authorization.

```
auth0 test token -a https://<your-auth0-domain>/api/v2/
```

Then, you can use it with something like HTTPie:

```
http :8080/hello Authorization:"Bearer $TOKEN"
```